# How to use KVO to detect when an application gets active?

Tags: macos, key-value-observing, nsworkspace, nsrunningapplication

I have the following code in a Cocoa application:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
   NSArray* arrayAppList = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
}
```

My intention is to use KVO to detect an application when changes its state between inactive to active.

I read that I have to use the instance method `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`

And then use `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` to respond to change notifications.

I understand that `-observeValueForKeyPath` is a callback method where I can write code to respond to the properties changes I am interested in.

Nevertheless, I feel confused in how I must to use the addObserver method in order to be notified when the `active` property of the `runningApplications` change.  Now, I am wondering where is the place to make the registration, for now I am using `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` but not sure if is the right place to do it.  Additionally if I use the `-observeValueForKeyPath` callback method, I have to implement it in the class that inherits from `NSObject` and is the same class where I am registering the notification?

Answer (score 4):

1. You should call the `addObserver:…` method on each object in the `runningApplications` array (using `isActive` as the key path).
2. Starting the observing after your app finishes launching sounds about right. Time-wise, that is. As for the place, there should be a separate class dedicated to these observations. By implementing the observation code right in the app delegate you would violate the single-responsibility principle (and that means headache in the long term).
3. The `observeValueForKeyPath:…` callback should be implemented by the object that called the `addObserver:…` methods.